# Lion Mail.app messages marking themselves as read

Tags: macos, mail.app, email, iphone

My boss is accessing his emails via the MAPI (Exchange) protocol using:

- The mail app on his iPhone 4S
- Mail.app version 5.3 on an iMac running OS X 10.7

For the most part everything works as expected: if he reads a message on his iPhone, the message turns to "read" on his iMac and vice versa. However, sometimes messages appear to automatically mark themselves as read after a time period of approximately one hour. I understand that messages in the Mail.app will turn to "read" the instant they are highlighted or clicked on, but that is not the situation I'm describing here. I can't find any settings in either application that would automatically mark a message as read after a certain time period.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm facing the exact same issue, did you manage to find an answer?

Answer (score 1):

This is strange. Are you sure he is not clicking on those mails in his phone? Or somebody else having access to it. Change the password for the email and check again, if this continues then the problem would be either in his phone or imac.

Try with password change and we will see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing the exact same problem. Lion and Mountain lion on an iMap account. If I leave the Mac Mail.app closed, the problem does not happen on the iPhone. Therefore, we know it has something to do with the Mac but cannot narrow it down further.